# Performing a date comparison with a MongoDB Find using only JSON

Tags: mongodb

As far as I can tell there seems to be no way to perform a `Find` lookup in MongoDB  that performs a Date `lte` without using either the `Date` or `ISODate` JavaScript constructor methods.

I am using a technology stack that uses `LUA` scripts that are invoked by a secondary `Perl` system. The issue is that I can only pass pure JSON between these systems and subsequently on to the MongoDB instance itself.

This presents a number off issues, the major one being that any JavaScript functions supported by Mongo are not an option. (Assuming there's no way to get Mongo to interpret functions stored within string values?)

Currently I can perform a `lte` lookup using the `Aggregate` method with something like:

```
{
    "$match": {
        "$expr": {
            "$and": {
                "$lte": {
                    "start_date": {
                        "$dateFromString": {
                            "dateString": "2020-06-07T04:44:39.993Z"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While this works, this is just for a single date comparison, it would be nice to be able to reduce the amount of code since I expect to be creating some fairly complex queries.

Ideally I would be able to use `Find` and do the following:

```
{
    "start_date": {
        "$lte": "2020-06-07T04:44:39.993Z"
    }
}
```

As far as I know `Find` doesn't seem to support `lte` date lookups using a string based Date value.

Things I've tried:

- Using various ISO and JavaScript formatted date strings.
- Using Epoch seconds and millisecond string values.
- Attempting to escape the JavaScript function calls within the string value.

Is what I am attempting to do at all possible? Is using pure JSON an option? Or do I just have to concede defeat and use the `Aggregate` function to perform the String to Date conversion and just deal with the additional boiler plate code or is there a fundamental thing I'm missing with Mongo that would let me do this?